# Apache Solr: order of facet values dependent on another facet

Tags: solr, faceted-search

My facets are automatically sorted by the facet integer value and then alphabetically, but I need the order in facet B to be dependent on the order in facet A.

Current result:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="label_nl_0">
        <int name="Accessoires">6</int>
        <int name="Audio / Music">6</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="slug_nl_0">
        <int name="aa-to-z-music">6</int>
        <int name="random-slug">6</int>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Desired result:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="label_nl_0">
        <int name="Accessoires">6</int>
        <int name="Audio / Music">6</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="slug_nl_0">
        <int name="random-slug">6</int>
        <int name="aa-to-z-music">6</int>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Whatever the order is in facet `label_nl_0`, the facet `slug_nl_0` should have the order that matches with the label_en/slug_en value as defined in the database (see below).

Here's how I get the data in Solr:

data-config.xml

```
SELECT label_en as label_en_0,slug_en as slug_en_0 FROM products WHERE id=@productid
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="slug_en_0" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="label_en_0" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

In the database I have products that are assigned two the following 2 categories (6 in the first category and another 6 in the second category). Products always are in exactly 1 category:

Category 1

> label_en  =   Accessories
>   slug_en       =   random-slug

Category 2

> label_en  =   Audio / Music
>   slug_en       =   aa-to-z-music

My Solr query:
http://localhost:8983/solr/shop/select/?indent=on&facet=true&sort=updatedate%20desc&start=0&rows=20&fl=id,titel&facet.mincount=1&fl=label_en_0,slug_en_0&facet.field=label_en_0&facet.field=slug_en_0&q=*:*

Comment: How about a field that has both values, and you split it in the UI to show the value relevant for the list .. or you could probably facet on the first field, and use the second as a pivot, but that would require you to display the first child of the facet when showing the second facet.

Comment: Thanks, seems like that field combining would be the best solution for me. Happy New Year!